# Replacing values in a Matrix: in each row, maximum value with minimum value

Tags: r, matrix, replace, max, min

I can't solve this problem, I am just beginning to learn R. Thanks for the help:

> (e) In each row of the matrix replace the maximum value with the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` to loop through the rows (`MARGIN = 1`) and `replace` the values that `max` with the `min` of that row

```
t(apply(m1, 1, function(x) replace(x, x== max(x), min(x))))
```

---

Or use row/column indexing to assign the elements are max per row to minimum of each row

```
library(matrixStats)
m1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(m1))] <- rowMins(m1)
```

Or using only `base R`

```
m1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(m1))] <- m1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(-m1))]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(rnorm(5* 10), 5, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, but I want to replace the values on each row.

Comment: @ChristianRondónReymer  It is replacing on each row